# constraint image inside imageview to android:background shape

Tags: android, android-layout

In my recycleview I have displayed a list of images/icons. These are transparent logos navigating to next activity. Some of the images I have are crossing the circles outlines.
I would like to add a max-height/max-width for the icon presented to eliminate this behaviour. Sometimes the icons are constraint not to the oval but to the square rounded parent layout (constraint) 
Is there any way to constraint an src image in xml? This is how it looks with Renault logo:

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Empty ImageView above. I changed the background colour to ilustrate the problem with constraints. I **do not want** to fill white space.

Comment: Is the first image what you want or what you want to avoid? In other words, is the Renault log currently extending outside the circle and that is what you don't want, or, should the circle clip the logo so it has a rounded top as shown in the first view. Maybe you want the entire logo to fit inside the circle?

Comment: I want entire logo to fit inside the circle. The issue is that i receive many of them with different sizez etc, and some ot them do not fit properly even though I am centering them. But they match the constraint of a square (parent)

Comment: Applying the appropriate  top and bottom padding on the ImageView will center the images within the circular background. The padding may be different for each image, though. Depending on the logo, you may have issues with the left and right sides not fitting. Left/right padding will solve those problems. There are no constraints to fit the circle without doing some computation on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below scale type

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```